# Differential of the norm in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: derivatives

We consider the normed vector space $(\mathbb{R}^n,\Vert\cdot\Vert)$.
Is the map $\Vert\cdot\Vert$ differentiable even if it is not induced by a scalar product?

Comment: Truth to be told, it's not differentiable (in $0$) when it's induced by a scalar product either.

Comment: A norm which is differentiable off the origin is called a "smooth norm".

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes yes, sometimes no.  For example, consider the $p$-norms:
$$
\|(x_1,\dots,x_n)\|_p = \left(\sum_{k=1}^n |x_k|^p\right)^{1/p} .
$$
This is differentiable (except at the origin) if $p>1$, but not if $p=1$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: thanks, edited.

Comment: It could also be remarked that even the 1-norm is differentiable almost everywhere -- namely at points where all the $x_i$s are nonzero.

Comment: And, more generally, any convex function is differentiable almost everywhere?

Comment: @GEdgar: yes https://math.stackexchange.com/q/727789/8157

Answer (score 2):

A norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is never differentiable at the origin. Let $x_0\in \mathbb{R}^n\setminus \left\{0\right\}$. Then
$$\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\|(0+tx_0)\|-\|0\|}{t} =\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\|t\|}{t}\|x_0\|$$
By the norm axiom $x_0\neq 0 \Rightarrow \|x_0\|\neq 0$, and so the limit does not exist, as
$$\lim_{t\to 0^+}\frac{\|t\|}{t}=1\neq -1=\lim_{t\to 0^-}\frac{\|t\|}{t} $$

On the other hand, the triangle inequality
$$\left|\|x\|-\|y\|\right|\leq \|x-y\| $$
 tells us that any norm in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is Lipschitz with Lipschitz constant $L=1$. Thus by [Rademacher's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rademacher%27s_theorem), it is differentiable almost everywhere in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: I like the reference to Rademacher's theorem but there is a subtlety. The theorem refers to the Euclidean norm on $\mathbb R^n$, but this answer only shows that $\lVert\cdot\rVert$ is 1-Lipschitz with respect to itself. To conclude that $\lVert \cdot \rVert$ is Lipschitz with respect to the Euclidean norm ($\ell^2$), we also need the inequality $$\lVert x\rVert \le C \lVert x\rVert_{\ell^2}.$$This inequality holds because all norms are equivalent on $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: Absolutely. I noticed that I was working with different norms but since we are working in $\mathbb{R}^n$ I did not worry about it :) but for a reader who is not familiar with this fact this is an important remark.

Answer (score 0):

A simple example of a norm on $\Bbb R^2$ which is non-differentiable at points other than the origin is given by $$||(x,y)||=\max(|x|,|y|).$$

If $h>0$ then $||(1+h,1)||=1+h$, while if $-2<h<0$ then $||(1+h,1)||=1$. Hence the function $h\mapsto||(1+h,1)||$ is not differentiable at $h=0$, so $||.||$ is not differentiable at $(1,1)$.