# Do gradients existing almost everywhere for a pointwise maximum function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, piecewise-continuity

Consider the following function: $f: \mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$
     $$f(x)=\max_{p\in\mathcal{P}} x^Tp$$
where $\mathcal{P}\in\mathbb{R}^n$ is a nonempty and compact set.

It is easy to see that $f(x)$ is a piecewise convex function but is it true that $f(x)$ has gradients almost everywhere? Any references and counterexamples are very welcome.

Comment: @NicNic8 Why is that? The only input of $f$ is $x$.

Comment: @Mathexx So we're assuming that the maximum always exists?

Comment: Related: [Danskin's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Danskin%27s_theorem)

Comment: @Sambo Yes, I have modified the question a little bit.

Comment: Please refer to a similar question here for the answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/727789/convex-function-almost-surely-differentiable?rq=1

Answer (score -1):

It is not actually the case that $f$ is always a piecewise convex function.  It depends completely on the set $\mathcal{P}$.

Onto your question, I assume by "almost everywhere" you mean that the set of non-differentiable points has measure $0$.

So, if $\mathcal{P}$ has measure $0$, then $f$ is differentiable "almost everywhere".

If $\mathcal{P}$ has non-zero measure, then it may be the case that $g$ is non-differentiable on a set with non-zero measure (some subset of $\mathcal{P}$ that has non-zero measure, perhaps $\mathcal{P}$ itself).

Comment: But what does it mean for $\mathcal{P}$ to have zero measure? It's not a subset of $\mathbb{R}$, it's just a general set.

Comment: I have modified the question and I think convexity should always hold this time.

Comment: @Sambo measure is not restricted to subsets of $\mathbb{R}$.  Measure is the "size" of the set.  It's a way of measuring how large it is.  Some examples of measure are length, area, volume.  Note that a set of isolated points has measure 0.

Comment: @NicNic8 I know that, but prior to the edit $\mathcal{P}$ was an arbitrary set, for which it doesn't make sense to talk about measure. What's the measure of, say, $\aleph_1 \backslash \aleph_0$?

Comment: @Sambo Even if it's arbitrary, if I can show that there are some sets where f is non-differentiable with non-zero measure, then it isn't differentiable "almost everywhere".

If you have another definition for "almost everywhere" please specify it.