# If ‎$\log f(x)$ ‎is ‎concave, t‎hen‎ it has derivative ‎$ ‎\frac{f^\prime_{-}(x) + f^\prime_{+}(x) ‎}{2f(x)}‎$.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, convex-analysis

‎I've been stuck with prove the following problem. Can you help me?‎‎‎

‎‎‎Suppose that ‎‎$‎f:‎\mathbb{R^+}‎‎‎\rightarrow‎‎\mathbb{R^+}‎$ is a function such that‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎ $\log f(x)‎$ ‎is ‎concave. ‎Then‎, it has derivative ‎‎$ ‎‎\frac{f^\prime_{-}(x) + f^\prime_{+}(x) ‎}{2f(x)}‎$ ‎except, possibly, on a countable set,

where ‎$‎f^\prime_{+}(x‏)‎$ ‎and ‎‎$‎f^\prime_{-}(x)‎$ ‎are ‎right ‎and ‎left ‎derivatives, ‎respectively. ‎
‎

Thanks‎ in advance.

Comment: Is the statement true? For $f(x)=x$ ($x \geq 0$), the statement boils down to $f'(x) = 1/x$, right?

Comment: @LinAlg It would boil down to $\frac{d}{dx}\log x = \frac{1}{x}$, so it's correct in this case. It's also very easy to prove in the differentiable case. You can just apply chain-rule.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/946311/a-convex-function-is-differentiable-at-all-but-countably-many-points

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, convex functions are differentiable a.e. (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/727789/convex-function-almost-surely-differentiable)). Note that the negation of a convex function is concave and vice versa, so we can use this differentiability result for concave functions. With this, we can define 
$$
h(x) = e^{(\log f(x))} = f(x)
$$
the composition of a function with is differentiable a.e. ( $\log f(x)$ in this case) and a function which is differentiable everywhere ($e^x$ in this case), will be differentiable a.e., and so $f(x)$ will be differentiable a.e. Therefore, when $f'(x)$ exists, we have $f'(x) = f'(x+) = f'(x-)$ and so 
$$
f'(x) = \frac{f'(x+) + f'(x-)}{2}
$$
**when the derivative exists**. The same composition argument can now be applied to $f(x)$ and $\log(x)$ to give 
$$
\frac{d}{dx} \log (f(x)) = \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} = \frac{f'(x+) + f'(x-)}{2f(x)}
$$
where the first inequality follows from the chain rule. Again, this is only when $f'(x)$ exists

Comment: What do you mean by "the negation of a convex function is concave"?

Comment: If $f(x)$ is a convex function, then $g(x) = -f(x)$ is concave. This follows from the definition of convex/concave functions

Comment: I know, just the word "negation" is ambiguous here.